# Using lstlisting environment withing macros?

Tags: macros, latex

I tried to define a macro, for me to quickly create a listing environment. The definition looked like that:

```
% \def \lstlistingcode[#1] { \begin{lstlisting}#1\end{lstlisting} }
```

which ends in an Error:

```
job aborted, no legal \end found
```

Is it possible to use environments within macros, and if yes - how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some environments can, e.g. alltt; however, lstlisting can't, because of how it is written (it apparently has to do with various catcode stuff that it does).

Using \def as you do is sort of outdated; \newcommand is preferred:

\newcommand \allttcode[1] { \begin{alltt}#1\end{alltt} }

...

\allttcode{test}