# LaTeX newcommand with verbatim or listings : problem with `#` (hash key)

Tags: macros, latex, special-characters, listings, verbatim

I'm trying to define a macro with `\newcommand` using `verbatim` or `listings` environment. It seems that the hash key in `#1` (standing for the argument) is escaped, due to `verbatim` and `listings`.

I'm new to macros, so I tried something simple : it works with  `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{report}
\newcommand{\script}[1]{
  \begin{center}
    #1
  \end{center}
}
\begin{document}
  \script{blabla}
  blibli
\end{document}
```

When I replace `center` with `verbatim`, I get this error :

> File ended while scanning use of @xverbatim.

or `lstlisting` :

> Text dropped after begin of listing

I didn't find anything on stackoverflow nor https://tex.stackexchange.com : what would you advise to use those environments in macros (`\newcommand` or maybe `\newenvironment`) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the aim here? Verbatim content cannot be passed as an argument to other macros.

Comment: I'd like 1) to paste scripts and code without having to escape characters 2) make a minipage or sthg else, maybe a box, to distinguish between code and normal text in the page.

Comment: By "scripts of code" are you referring to the actual code? I would suggest writing your own environment based on [`listings`](//ctan.org/pkg/listings).

Comment: I'm making a tutorial in which I use PHP, bash, Sparql. But I'd like to paste any text with special chars. What do you mean with > writing your own environment based on listings. ? Is there a simple manner to do so (haven't found yet)?

Comment: Same question on TeX.SE [listings - How to define macro that only makes argument substitution? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42144/how-to-define-macro-that-only-makes-argument-substitution?noredirect=1&lq=1) // Same question on SO: [latex - Using lstlisting environment withing macros? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483987/using-lstlisting-environment-withing-macros)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verbatim content is tricky. You have to ask yourself what the intent is. If it's printing code, then king of the hill would be [`listings`](//ctan.org/pkg/listings). I'd suggest that and define your own environment for large chunks of code-specific output.

Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{code}[1][]
  {\lstset{#1}}% Add/update settings locally
  {}

\lstset{% Global options
  frame = single,
  basicstyle = \ttfamily\small,
  language = PHP
}

\begin{document}

My first PHP ``Hello World'' page:

\begin{code}
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
 </body>
</html>
\end{code}

When you write \lstinline!<title>PHP Test</test>!, it sets the \textit{title} of the page.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Werner, you convinced me to learn more about `listings`. Didn't know of `\lstinline`. Could you just explain the syntax of `{\lstset{#1}}` : does it mean I can add an option as argument?

Comment: @vvffl: Yes. I defined `code` as an environment that can take an optional argument. So you can call (say) `\begin{code}[language = bash]`...`\end{code}` to switch the `language`. It would probably be ideal for you to define a *style* depending on the language (styles include colour and other formatting specifications).

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I thought (I have somewhere in my tex files an old paper where I used custom syntax color for xml, so I'm going to 'grep' that first). So macros aren't that difficult, but the syntax still looks weird for me.

Comment: Last question : do you know if there's a way to preserve indentation and prevent wrong spaces (e. g. in your example, before '>') when you copy the code from the pdf output to a text editor?

Comment: @vvffl: This is a common requirement, but it's not well-supported. See [Viewer-independent copyable spaces at the beginning of a line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148144/5764) The fact that the output (in the resulting PDF) does not include the spaces, they aren't selectable for copy-and-paste. As such, indentation is not preserved. The intent of (La)TeX is to produce beautiful documents and therefore might not fully support the "reverse" where that content is copied/pasted elsewhere.

Comment: @vvffl: You can try [Copy-pasting leading whitespace and blank lines in listings package (PDF)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142617/5764), which uses [`accsupp`](//ctan.org/pkg/accsupp).

Comment: Thank you so much for the tips, it saved a lot of time (browsing latex-stackexchange...)

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround for `verbatim` with `\verb` command, and using tilde as delimiter (if I want to use tilde inside the script I have to use `\textasciitilde`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\scr}[1]{
    \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth} 
        \fbox{
            \parbox{\textwidth}{            
                \verb~#1~               % <-- HERE
            }
        }
    \end{minipage}  
}   

\begin{document}        
    \scr{Some script code here... 

    here a tilde : \textasciitilde
    }
\end{document}
```

But nothing for `listings`...

---

EDIT : 
I've just noticed that this workaround doesn't keep the "automatic" character escaping, so it's not what I was looking for. I'd like to be able to paste code without escaping special chars.

Comment: This does not work. Within a `verbatim` setting (either within the `verbatim` environment or `\verb`) macros like `\textasciitilde` are not expanded to their meaning since ``\`` is changed to represent a character. As such, your output should contain `\textasciitilde`, not `~`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually it does work on my install... Don't know how nor why!